# Can we derandomize subexponential algorithms given P=BPP?

Tags: complexity-theory, randomized-algorithms, randomness

Under $BPP=P$ conjecture randomization does not have much power for poly time algorithms.

Can we say the same about randomized subexp algorithms like number field sieve?

Comment: Have you tried the padding trick? Pad the input so that the algorithm now runs in polynomial time, derandomize it, and then "unpad".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus aha so randomized algorithms can always be derandomized (no matter running time)?

Comment: Padding only works in one direction, though. Try to write this argument formally, and so answer your own question. Also, when I say "derandomize", I mean use the conjecture $P=BPP$. Everything is conditional anyhow.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus When you say padding this is what i understand. pad input to make longer so subexp becomes poly in new input and $P=BPP$ implies randomization is not powerful for this new input and removing padding implies $BPSUBEXP$ is same as $SUBEXP$.

Comment: Right, that's the idea.

Comment: Note that, as far as I'm aware, the possibility of {BPP=P but [MA](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#ma)≠NP} has not been ruled out. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ (See [∃BPP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#existsbpp).) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer how is your comment related to $BPSUBEXP$ derandomization and padding  argument?

Comment: It's not; it's related to the power of randomization for poly time algorithms for [promise problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem). ​ ​

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Derandomization results transfer "upwards" using the technique of padding. Assume $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{BPP}$. Suppose that some problem $A$ can be solved in randomized superpolynomial time $t(n)$ (which is time-constructible). Let $A'$ be the same problem, but with inputs padded to length $t(n)$. Then $A' \in \mathsf{BPP} = \mathsf{P}$. The following algorithm then solves $A$ in deterministic time $t(n)$: pad the input to length $t(n)$, then apply the polynomial time algorithm for $A'$.

Conversely, it is possible (given the current state of knowledge) that subexponential time algorithms can be randomized, but polynomial time algorithms can't (and it might be possible to construct a relativized world in which this happens unconditionally). That is, results don't transfer "downwards".